# react ie fetch Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, fetch, babeljs

i can not let react support ie , ie brower console display Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Network request failed

i use react create my app , the app does not ie brower, i try to solve the isse,i try to import whatwg-fetch,i am fail.i do not how to do solve ie brower problem.

```
import "whatwg-fetch";
import "@babel/polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you provide more details about request and did you try to test  it in external tool like  postman.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your app is working on other browsers but it is showing the above mentioned error only in IE browser and app not loading than it can be possible that you did not added the correct polyfills for IE browser.

By default, the generated project supports all modern browsers. Support for Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 requires polyfills. For a set of polyfills to support older browsers, [use react-app-polyfill.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md)

you did not mentioned, which version of IE browser you are using for making this test. I assume that you are using IE 11.

First, install the package using Yarn or npm:

```
npm install react-app-polyfill

//or

yarn add react-app-polyfill
```

For IE11:

```
// These must be the first lines in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

// ...
```

Also try to add line below in your HTML file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Is your issue solved? If yes, please mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. if you found the solution by yourself than post the solution and mark it as an answer. If your issue is still exist than please let us know about the current status of the issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. thanks for your understanding.